# How to query subcategory

Tags: sql

**tableA**:

```
name    |  date         |  con
------------------------------
tv      | 2017-07-01    |   1
tv      | 2017-07-02    |   1
tv      | 2017-07-03    |   1
tv      | 2017-07-03    |   2
mobil   | 2017-07-03    |   1
mobil   | 2017-07-04    |   1
tablet  | 2017-07-03    |   1
tablet  | 2017-07-03    |   2
tablet  | 2017-07-03    |   3
```

**tableB**:

```
name     |  date         |  was
------------------------------
tv       | 2017-07-01    |   15
mobil    | 2017-07-03    |   50
mobil    | 2017-07-04    |   15
tablet   | 2017-07-04    |   30
```

result tableA (no problem):

```
select  name,
Group_concat( cons) as conA
from(
select  name,
count(con) as cons
from tableA 
where 
date between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
GROUP BY con, name 
HAVING con>0) q
GROUP BY name;
```

How to combine `tableA` & `tableB`? 
left join -> I did not try?
subcategory -> I did not try?
how should I do

Desired Output:

```
name   |  conA   |  wasB |
------- --------  -------- 
tv     |   3,1   |  15   |
mobil  |   4     |  65   |
tablet |   9,1,1 |  30   |
```

Comment: please makes more readable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use count(*) in subselelect and sum for was

```
select q.name,
  Group_concat( q.cons) as conA, wasB
  from( 
    select name,
    count(*) as cons
    from tableA 
    where 
    date between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
    GROUP BY con, name 
    HAVING con>0) q
  left  JOIN (
    select name, sum(was)  wasB
    from tableB
    group by name
  ) b on q.name = b.name
  GROUP BY name
```

Comment: wasB false (total)

Comment: what do you mean ???

Comment: wasB  
15   | 
195   |
100   |  
Wrong result

Comment: answer  updated .

Comment: dear scaisEdge,Thank you so much